# Uniqueness of the LUP decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, lu-decomposition

Given the matrix $$A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 2 & 2 & 3 \end{pmatrix},$$ I want to compute the LUP decomposition $PA=LU$.

Here's what I got:
$$P=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
$$L=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1/2 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} $$
$$U=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 2 & 3  \\ 0 & 1 & 1.5 \\ 0 & 0& 2 \end{pmatrix}$$

[WolframAlpha says it's correct](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%7B%7B0%2C0%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B1%2C0%2C0%7D%7D*%7B%7B0%2C0%2C2%7D%2C%7B1%2C2%2C3%7D%2C%7B2%2C2%2C3%7D%7D%3D%7B%7B1%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B1%2F2%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C1%7D%7D*%7B%7B2%2C2%2C3%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C1.5%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C2%7D%7D).

The solution says:

$$ \begin{array}{l}\left(\begin{array}{lll}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right) \cdot\left(\begin{array}{lll}0 & 0 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 2 & 2 & 3\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{lll}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{array}\right) \cdot\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1 & 2 & 3 \\ 0 & -2 & -3 \\ 0 & 0 & 2\end{array}\right) \\ =P \cdot A=L \cdot R\end{array}$$

Again, [WolframAlpha says it's correct](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%7B%7B0%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C0%2C0%7D%7D*%7B%7B0%2C0%2C2%7D%2C%7B1%2C2%2C3%7D%2C%7B2%2C2%2C3%7D%7D%3D%7B%7B1%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B2%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C1%7D%7D*%7B%7B1%2C2%2C3%7D%2C%7B0%2C-2%2C-3%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C2%7D%7D).

Both seem to work? My permutation matrix switches the third and the first row, the solution the first and the second. The permutation matrix in the solution manual switches the second and the first row.

When I compute the LU decomposition using WolframAlpha, I get the solution of the book ... see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=LU%20decomposition%20of%20%7B%7B0%2C0%2C2%7D%2C%7B1%2C2%2C3%7D%2C%7B2%2C2%2C3%7D%7D).

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of the definite article in “the LUP decomposition” is unwarranted. LUP decompositions aren’t unique (an answer to [Is the permutation matrix P of PLU decomposition unique?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3719119) shows that it’s not even unique if $L$ or $U$ is required to have $1$s on the diagonal), so no explanation is required for the fact that you found more than one LUP decomposition for a given matrix.

Comment: Thanks! I saw the question you linked aswell, one of the answers said it was unique, hence my confusion.

Comment: @Analysis: Yes, the reasoning in that answer is flawed. Next time, it would be good to include that in your question if you already found a related question and answer.

Comment: Will do! Thanks for the advice.